# Create django Response() from a collection of data not contained in a table/model?

Tags: django-rest-framework

On my django backend, I am collecting a bunch of data from various sources. Some data comes directly from tables. Some is calculated from table data. Some is collected from the user's browser header. There may be current date & time info. Basically, I have a mass of data that is not in a database table. Therefore I have no model and no serializer. I don't want to create a table just to hold data that does not need to be stored at all. How do I return this data as a Response to a GET request from the user frontend?

e.g., django keeps session variables in a table, but encrypted. You can access individual session variables by name, but you can't GET them directly from the table. I keep the registrant ID number as a session variable in request.session['registrant_id']. How do I include that value in a response without making another copy of it in a table?

Every tutorial and example shows serializers based on models.